# Reference return by window.open() is Undefined in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

The following code isn’t working for Edge though it works for other browsers.

```js
function postLink(locn, trgt) {
  a = document.createElement("a");
  a.id = 'link';
  a.targt = trgt;
  a.href = locn;
  var newwin = window.open(a);
  newwin.opener = newwin;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="postLink('http://www.google.com','_blank');return false;">ClickMe</a>
```

It gives `newwin` is `undefined`. Whereas, `window.open()` works for Edge.
Any explanation / help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think that you can pass an `a` element as an argument to that function. It takes up to three strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open . Also, I think what you're doing is better accomplished by setting `target='_blank'` on the `<a>` element, and just setting `href` to google.com - so no javascript.

Comment: Since, the code is working for other browser. I suppose we can do this. Also, implementation is a part of other large program but it is breaking at this particular piece of code. Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I get `InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object` in Firefox. Why is there no `var` keyword before `a`? And `Open` is definitely undefined. What you mean is `open`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/iconsid/6w8es5mq/ its working here as expected without any error except edge browser.

Comment: I can't answer as to why certain undefined behavior (passing the wrong parameter type) ever works, but the explanation for it *not* working (again, wrong parameter type) makes sense to me. Is there any reason you're interested in doing it the non-documented way? Browsers have often tried to gently accept bad data/methods, but they're never really required to.

Comment: @katana314 I understand your concern and you are right at this part but its a configurable piece of code where in xml user can define all the parameters for a link and at runtime everything rendered accordingly. But for edge it a'nt working.

Comment: @SiddharthaGupta You just restated the information from your question. That doesn't preempt anything I just said. You are passing in the wrong parameters, and there is no reason it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From the `window.open()` docs:

> Syntax:
>   window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

So, why not simplify your code to this:

```
<a onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank');">ClickMe</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3aaLjjoh/

Comment: I can't do this as its a configurable piece of code for a large program where user will have an option to chose the target type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function and simply pass in the target to parameter 2.

```
function openWindow(url, name = "_blank", width = 400, height = 600, top = 25, left = 25) {
    window.open(url, name, 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0,top=' + top + ',left=' + left + ',width=' + width + ',height=' + height);
}

<a onclick="openWindow('http://www.google.com','_blank');">ClickMe</a>
```